# play framework 2.1 accees log

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm writing a play framework 2.1.5 access log, code like this

```
class AccessLog extends Filter {
  def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Result)(rh: RequestHeader) = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis

    def logTime(result: PlainResult): Result = {
      val time = System.currentTimeMillis - start
      val contentLength: String = result.header.headers getOrElse("Content-Length", "-") 
      play.Logger.info("" + rh.method +"  " + rh.uri + " took " + "  " +  time + " ms and returned " + result.header.status + "  " + contentLength)
      result
    }

    next(rh) match {
      case plain: PlainResult => logTime(plain)
      case async: AsyncResult => async.transform(logTime)
    }
  }
}
```

I found that many people found an access log for the play framework and this works any way with an issue that 
it can always get the response size, when you press CTRL + F5, if you just press F5, you cannot get the "Content-Length" even the "Content-Length" does not exist in the map.
any one konw this?

Comment: It's incredibly complicated to get the content length at this level. Not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: @Julien Lafont  do you have any idea about this?